Kafka TLS cert Issue
I'm using kafka_2.13-3.5.0 , and I had encountered an issue. Say if the server hostname command returns 'kaf-d-p1-123456.sys.net' and the the same server has a DNS 'A Record' which is 'kaf-a-p1.sys.net'. I created the certs with the hostname for a cluster and it worked but when i tried to use the A Record for creating the certs. there is a SSH authentication failed log. Please help me with the potential reason for the issue and fix. I looked into it and saw this may be due to hostname mismatch. can that be the case.
I expect for the kafka cluster to work as expected with both certs created with FQDN and A Record. The only thing that works now is the FQDN cert.
